# What role does alcoholic liquid play in cheese fondue recipes?

Tags: cheese, wine, beer, fondue

Pretty much every recipe I've seen for cheese fondue includes either [white](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/tyler-florence/cheese-fondue-recipe/index.html) [wine](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/cheese-fondue/) (sometimes [alongside kirsch](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/sauces/r/fondue.htm)/brandy) or [some kind](http://southernfood.about.com/od/fonduerecipes/r/blbb562.htm) of [beer](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/rachael-ray/german-cheddar-and-beer-fondue-recipe/index.html) in the delicious cheesy sauce.

Why is the added liquid (seemingly) always alcoholic - as opposed to adding, say, water? Is it because beer or wine complements the other flavors in the fondue, or because milk proteins [are alcohol soluble](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1260729/pdf/biochemj01119-0082.pdf) so it achieves the desired consistency? Or is there some other reason that combines those two explanations (or presents a different one entirely)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advertised reason is that the alcohol will cut some of the protein chains resulting in a fondue that is dippable and not so stringy. Obviously the alcoholic beverage of choice will also add a lot of cheese-compatible flavor as well.

Fondue recipes that don't include alcohol universally call for acid to achieve a similar effect.